# Why is an error saying 'Non real answers' arising from the following integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

In order to get the value of the following integral, I use a graphing calculator to obtain the solution to the definite integral:
[Definite Integral (time)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6GRC.png)

The calculator is showing 'Error due to non real values'. I do not understand why this is happening. I also used a different calculator; however, the same arises.

How do I solve for the definite integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integrand is imaginary after $x=\sqrt{\frac{.6852}{.000174}}\simeq 62.7529$

Comment: So a real solution doesn't exist?

Comment: Right solution is complex